# Getting error while trying to install web3

Tags: web3js

getting following error while running **npm install -g web3**

> web3@1.0.0-beta.13 postinstall C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3
>   lerna bootstrap

```
lerna info version 2.0.0
lerna info Bootstrapping 19 packages
lerna info lifecycle preinstall
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! execute Error: Command failed: npm install
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR! Can't install C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-bzz: Missin
g package name
lerna ERR! execute
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR!     C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-01T06_44_24_043Z-debug.log
lerna ERR! execute
lerna ERR! execute     at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\node_modules\execa\
index.js:210:11)
lerna ERR! execute     at <anonymous>
lerna ERR! execute     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
lerna ERR! execute  callback with error
lerna ERR! execute  { Error: Command failed: npm install
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR! Can't install C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-bzz: Missin
g package name
lerna ERR! execute
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
lerna ERR! execute npm ERR!     C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-01T06_44_24_043Z-debug.log
lerna ERR! execute
lerna ERR! execute     at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\node_modules\execa\
index.js:210:11)
lerna ERR! execute     at <anonymous>
lerna ERR! execute     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
lerna ERR! execute   stack: 'Error: Command failed: npm install\nnpm ERR! Can\'t install C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Roam
ing\\npm\\node_modules\\web3\\packages\\web3-bzz: Missing package name\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be fou
nd in:\nnpm ERR!     C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2017-08-01T06_44_24_043Z-debug.log\n\n    at
Promise.all.then.arr (C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\web3\\node_modules\\execa\\index.js:210:11)
\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)',
lerna ERR! execute   code: 1,
lerna ERR! execute   killed: false,
lerna ERR! execute   stdout: '',
lerna ERR! execute   stderr: 'npm ERR! Can\'t install C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\web3\\packa
ges\\web3-bzz: Missing package name\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     C:\\Users\\sum
it\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2017-08-01T06_44_24_043Z-debug.log\n',
lerna ERR! execute   failed: true,
lerna ERR! execute   signal: null,
lerna ERR! execute   cmd: 'npm install',
lerna ERR! execute   timedOut: false }
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 3 child processes to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
(node:19328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Command failed: npm
 install
npm ERR! Can't install C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-bzz: Missing package name

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-01T06_44_24_043Z-debug.log

(node:19328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejection
s that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:19328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Command failed: npm
 install
npm ERR! Can't install C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-utils: Missing package name

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-01T06_44_24_041Z-debug.log

(node:19328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 9): Error: Command failed: npm
 install
npm ERR! Can't install C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-eth-abi: Missing package name

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-01T06_44_24_114Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! web3@1.0.0-beta.13 postinstall: `lerna bootstrap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the web3@1.0.0-beta.13 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: npm install web3@0.19
This worked for me .
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in this github issue : https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/923
you have to downgrade the web3js version instead 1.0.0 use [0.20.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) (The current stable version is 0.20.0) or less. 
Please try : `npm install web3@0.19`

Comment: Events doesn't work in lower version of web3.

Comment: That worked perfectly, is there any solution to install 'hooked-web3-provider'?

Comment: I used `npm install web3@0.19` but it says `found 39 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 moderate, 36 high)`. I want to use `web3-eth-accounts` module through `require("web3-eth-accounts")` but it says module doesn't exist even after installation.